# Python: creating categorical variable in the existing column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have a DataFrame in python that has a column holding difference of 2 dates. I would like to create a new/overwrite on the existing column that can convert numeric to categorical variable based on below rules:

```
difference              0 days    Level 0
difference              2 days    Level 1
difference              2-6 days  Level 2
difference             6-15 days  Level 3
difference             15-69 days Level 4
difference             NAT        Level 5
```

how this could be accomplished.

Comment: Do you have input data? And expected output?

Comment: is your difference column an `int` (e.g. 2), a `string` (e.g. ' days') or a `timedelta`?

Comment: I used `dtype` command, and the output is `dtype('<m8[ns]')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

say the column name is 'difference'

you can define a method like

```
def get_difference_category(difference):
    if difference < 0:
        return 0
    if difference <=2:
        return 1
    #.. and so on

df['difference'] = df['difference'].apply(lambda value: get_difference_category(value), axis=1)
```

reference links: 
https://github.com/vi3k6i5/pandas_basics/blob/master/2_b_apply_a_function_row_wise.ipynb

https://github.com/vi3k6i5/pandas_basics/blob/master/2_c_apply_a_function_to_a_column.ipynb

Comment: This approach helped.

Answer (score 1):

## Edit: To handle NaT, You can use `pd.cut`:

```
data['Severity'] = pd.cut((data['End'] - data['Start']).dt.days,[-pd.np.inf,-1,0,2,6,15,69],labels=['Level 5', 'Level 0','Level 1','Level 2','Level 3','Level 4']).fillna('Level 5')
```

Example:

```
df.head(10)

       Start        End
0 2017-01-01 2017-01-11
1 2017-01-02 2017-03-09
2 2017-01-03 2017-03-16
3 2017-01-04 2017-01-10
4 2017-01-05 2017-01-25
5 2017-01-06 2017-01-25
6 2017-01-07 2017-01-26
7 2017-01-08 2017-01-15
8 2017-01-09 2017-02-16
9 2017-01-10 2017-01-24


df['Severity'] = pd.cut((df['End'] - df['Start']).dt.days,[-np.inf,0,2,6,15,69,np.inf],labels=['Level 0','Level 1','Level 2','Level 3','Level 4','Level 5'])
```

Output:

```
          End      Start Severity
0  2017-01-11 2017-01-01  Level 3
1  2017-03-09 2017-01-02  Level 4
2  2017-03-16 2017-01-03  Level 5
3  2017-01-10 2017-01-04  Level 2
4  2017-01-25 2017-01-05  Level 4
5  2017-01-25 2017-01-06  Level 4
6  2017-01-26 2017-01-07  Level 4
7  2017-01-15 2017-01-08  Level 3
8  2017-02-16 2017-01-09  Level 4
9  2017-01-24 2017-01-10  Level 3
```

Comment: Thanks Scott. This is partially working. The scenario where start date is Null, and hence the difference is NAT, I would like to add `Level 5`, but currently it is giving me Null values

Comment: @user4943236 Okay, I modified the statement to handle NaT's.  Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `np.searchsorted` to find where each time delta falls into an array of break points.  I replace any `NaT` differences with `Level 6`

```
td = pd.to_timedelta(['0 days', '2 days', '6 days', '15 days', '69 days'])
difs = df.End.values - df.Start.values
vals = np.searchsorted(td.values, difs)
vals[pd.isnull(difs)] = 6

df = df.assign(
    Level=np.core.defchararray.add(
        'Level ', vals.astype(str)
    )
)
df

       Start        End    Level
0 2017-01-01 2017-01-11  Level 3
1 2017-01-02 2017-03-09  Level 4
2 2017-01-03 2017-03-16  Level 5
3 2017-01-04 2017-01-10  Level 2
4 2017-01-05 2017-01-05  Level 0
5 2017-01-06 2017-01-08  Level 1
6 2017-01-07 2017-01-26  Level 4
7 2017-01-08 2017-01-15  Level 3
8 2017-01-09 2017-02-16  Level 4
9 2017-01-10 2017-01-24  Level 3
```

---

**Setup**

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

txt = """       Start        End
0 2017-01-01 2017-01-11
1 2017-01-02 2017-03-09
2 2017-01-03 2017-03-16
3 2017-01-04 2017-01-10
4 2017-01-05 2017-01-05
5 2017-01-06 2017-01-08
6 2017-01-07 2017-01-26
7 2017-01-08 2017-01-15
8 2017-01-09 2017-02-16
9 2017-01-10 2017-01-24"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(txt), delim_whitespace=True).apply(pd.to_datetime)
```

Comment: plus1, I think the fastest.

Answer (score 0):

I added an bar plot to analyze the distribution.  I also used a dataframe and a lambda function to get my day differences. Visuals help you understand the data.  the histogram gives you insight into classification distributions and the pairplot shows you how the day interval is distributed.

```
column1=['2017-01-01','2017-01-01','2017-01-02','2017-01-03','2017-01-04','2017-01-05','2017-01-06','2017-01-07','2017-01-08','2017-01-09','2017-01-10']        
column2=['2017-01-01','2017-01-11','2017-03-09','2017-03-16','2017-01-10','2017-01-25','2017-01-25','2017-01-26','2017-01-15','2017-02-16','2017-01-24' ]

index=range(0,len(column1))
data={'column1':column1,'column2':column2}
df=pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['column1','column2'],index=index)
print(df.head())

differences=df.apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x['column2'],'%Y-%m-%d')-          datetime.strptime(x['column1'],'%Y-%m-%d'),axis=1)
differences=differences.dt.days.astype('int')
years_bins=[-1,0,2,6,15,69,np.inf]
output_labels=['level 0','level 1','level 2','level 3','level 4','level 5']    

out=pd.cut(differences,bins=years_bins,labels=output_labels)
df['differences']=differences
df['classification']=out

print(df.head())

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax = out.value_counts(sort=False).plot.barh(rot=0, color="b", figsize=(6,4))
ax.set_yticklabels(labels)
plt.show()
plt.hist(df['classification'], bins=6)
plt.show()

sns.distplot(df['differences'])
plt.show()
```